# Is there a way to fix no output and error in python terminal?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm new to python, and I'm trying to combine multiple excel files into a single data frame with pandas. When I run the code, I expect to get "Process finished with exit code 0", and a new file created in the folder path provided, instead I get no output and no error message. Please am I doing something wrong?

````
import pandas as pd
import glob

location = "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Documents\\capstone_project\\further-analysis\\*xlsx"

excel_files = glob.glob(location)

df1 = pd.DataFrame()

for files in excel_files:
    df2 = pd.read_excel(files)
    df1 = pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True)

df1.to_excel('C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Documents\\capstone_project\\further-analysis\\trip_data.xlsx')```
````

Comment: Try adding a `print` statement to find out what's in `excel_files` and maybe add something similar in the `for` loop? That may help narrow down what's going wrong

Comment: not doing anything wrong. There's no error (so no error message), no warnings from a package generated (so no warning messages), and no print statements, so nothing output in terminal. You could end the script with `print('Complete')` if you'd like an output in the terminal. Otherwise your file should be there.

Comment: I think the running time was taking too long, I'd been waiting for minutes, and just got a "ValueError: This sheet is too large"